# Create an Array from Json Object

Tags: arrays, json, delphi, rad-studio

I have the following JSON structure, calling it from web:

```json
[
  {
    "Code":"31212",
    "Desc":"JOHN",
    "DOYDESC":"MADRID",
    "Street":"Str41",
    "StreetNo":"86"
  },
  {
    "Code":"30214",
    "Desc":"GEORGE",
    "DOYDESC":"NEW YORK",
    "Street":"Str3",
    "StreetNo":null
  },
  {
    "Code":"09215",
    "Desc":"MARY",
    "DOYDESC":"PARIS",
    "Street":"Str3",
    "StreetNo":"22"
  },
  {
    "Code":"10217",
    "Desc":"MEGAN",
    "DOYDESC":"ROME",
    "Street":"Str4",
    "StreetNo":null
  }
]
```

I want the user to give a number in `Edit.Text`, and then search the values of `Code` to find if the given value exists.

Is there a way to create an array named `Code` with the values from the JSON?

For example, to create something like this:

```
Code = ["31212","30214","09215","10217"]
```

and then make the search? Or, is there another way to find a specific value of `Code` from the JSON? I tried this so far:

```pascal
procedure Tlog_form.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jso : TJsonObject;
  jsv,jsval : TJsonValue;
  jsa,jsarr : TJsonArray;
  data,str : string;
  i,j,user : integer;
  jsp : TJsonPair;
  arr : array of string;
begin
  try
    data := GetURLAsString('http://...');
  except
    on E: exception do
  end;

  try
    jsv := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(data);

    try
      jsa := jsv as TJSONArray;

      try
        for I := 0 to jsa.Size - 1 do
        begin
          jso := jsa.Get(i) as TJsonObject;
          if jso.ToString = 'Code' then
          begin
            str := jso.GetValue('Code').ToString;

            if Edit1.Text = str then
            begin
              ShowMessage('found it');
            end;

          end;
        end;
      finally
      end;
    finally
      jsv.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: exception do
  end;
end;
```

When I debug, it doesn't get any error. but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting each `TJSONObject` in the array to a `string`, and then comparing that to your `TEdit` text.  Which will obviously not match.  You need to compare only the `Code` field of each `TJSONObject`, which you would be doing if you remove the `if jso.ToString = 'Code' then` check completely, eg:

```pascal
procedure Tlog_form.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsv : TJSONValue;
  jsa : TJSONArray;
  jso : TJSONObject;
  data, str, code : string;
  I : integer;
begin
  str := Edit1.Text;
  try
    data := GetURLAsString('http://...');
    jsv := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(data);
    if jsv <> nil then
    try
      jsa := jsv as TJSONArray;
      for I := 0 to jsa.Size - 1 do
      begin
        jso := jsa.Get(I) as TJSONObject;
        code := jso.GetValue('Code').ToString;
        if str = code then
        begin
          ShowMessage('found it');
        end;
      end;
    finally
      jsv.Free;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand you very well, but if you try `TALJsonDocument` (https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe), you have this function:

```
Function ALFindJsonNodeByTextChildNodeValue(const JsonNode:TalJsonNode;
                                            Const ChildNodeName: AnsiString;
                                            Const ChildNodeValue : AnsiString;
                                            Const Recurse: Boolean = False): TALJsonNode;
```